# Как скачивать сразу несколько файлов по ссылкам?

Tags: python

у меня есть ссылки которые заданы по одному типу, я использую перебор для скачивания файлов

```
import urllib.request

for B in range(1, 8):
    for D in range(1, 8):
        for H in range(1, 8):
            for Alpha in [25, 16]:
                for angle in range(0, 105, 5):
                 try:
                    url = f'http://www.EXAMPLE/T{B}{D}{H}_{Alpha}_{angle}.mat'
                    urllib.request.urlopen(url)
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,
                                               f'{path}/T{B}{D}{H}_{Alpha}_{angle}.mat')
                except:
                    break
```

но файла по моей ссылке может и не быть, поэтому использую try except, но мне кажется, что urlopen работает медленно, как улучшить код, или может кто знает лучший способ для скачивания ?

Comment: Смотрте в сторону threading или multiprocessing. Можно еще в asyncio

Comment: но готовьтесь к приключениям. темы нелёгкие.